# Array not working as intended in get_terms function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, syntax-error

I'm invoking the WordPress `get_terms` function but I want to exclude multiple categories.

Why is this not valid?

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category', 'exclude' = array(1, 238) );
```

I find that I have to use this:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array('exclude' => array(1, 238),) );
```

but it seems redundant because there's only one item in the higher order array.

Documentation for reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$taxonomy  = 'review-product';

$post_type = 'reviews';

$args = [

    'post_type' => $post_type,

    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'terms'    => get_terms( $taxonomy, [ 'fields' => 'ids'  ] ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ]
    ]
];

$query = new \WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Can you please explain or annotate the lines of code as I am new to PHP.  Thank you.